# How to compare an expression to a string in groovy IF statement

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I have the following IF condition in my groovy script:

```html
if (git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an' == 'xyz')
```

Here all i am trying to achieve is that i need to have the value of

```html
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'
```

equate to some string lets say here xyz
I can easily do that in shell as below

```html
if [ `git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'` == "xyz" ]
```

But unable to get that to work in my groovy IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use it in Jenkinsfile

```
def log = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'").trim()
if (log == 'xyz') {
  ...
}
```

If you use it in pure Groovy (below solution also work in Jenkinfile)

```
def log = "git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'".execute().text
if (log == 'xyz') {
  ...
}
```