# How to convert a jenkins boolean param into all caps "TRUE" or "FALSE" string parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I have the following defined in my multibranch declarative pipeline:

```
steps {
  script {
    BUILD_PROD_FLAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "[ ${BUILD_PROD} = true ] && echo TRUE || echo FALSE; ").trim()
    BUILD_PROD_FLAG_SECOND = expression { if (params.BUILD_PROD) { return "TRUE" } else { return "FALSE" } }
  }
  sh "echo alternative way to get true/false set (want this to say FALSE): ${BUILD_FLAG_SECOND}"  
}
```

The first variable `BUILD_PROD_FLAG` works fine.
I would like to eliminate the convoluted bash spawning employed there.

The second one does not work:

`Multibranch_PR-1@tmp/durable-212f3652/script.sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/workspace/s_InsightCamera_Multibranch_PR-1@tmp/durable-212f3652/script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

This apparently is due to

[image]

Which I am not able to comprehend.

When the `expression block` is removed it fails to parse:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 67: unexpected token: if @ line 67, column 57.
             BUILD_FLAG_SECOND = if (params
                                 ^

1 error
```

And when I tried something else that is different:

```
BUILD_FLAG_SECOND = expression { return params.BUILD_PROD ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" }
```

I get the same `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error. I don't understand why this is a `.sh` shell script, by the way.

**Update**: OK I think I get why it's a .sh, that's just the `sh` clause near the bottom that I have.

I also thought I solved it because I did neglect to quote things for the shell, but with the adjustment:

```
sh "echo 'alternative way to get true/false set (want this to say FALSE):' ${BUILD_FLAG_SECOND}"
```

Still the same error:

[image]

I think it is for real trying to interpolate the string `@expression(<anonymous>=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@4a286654)` in place of the `BUILD_FLAG_SECOND` variable...

Answer (score 0):

Are you ready for the epic facepalm that is the solution?

`BUILD_FLAG_SECOND = params.BUILD_PROD ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"`

That's it.

Comment: Staring at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63066767/340947 and the code I am editing gave me the clues I needed to connect the dots. But I'm pretty sad that I didn't try this initially, because it is blindingly obvious.